# How to pass a operator as a parameter

Tags: chisel

I'm trying to pass an operator to a module so the module can be built generically.  I pass a two-input operator parameter and then use it in a reduction operation.  If I replace the passed parameter with a concrete operator this works OK.

What's the correct way to pass a Chisel/UInt/Data operator as a module parameter?

```
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Vec(n, Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(width.W))))
    val z = Decoupled(UInt(width.W))
  })
  val a_int = for (n <- 0 until n) yield DCInput(io.a(n))
  val z_int = Wire(Decoupled(UInt(width.W)))

  val all_valid = a_int.map(_.valid).reduce(_ & _)
  z_int.bits := a_int.map(_.bits).reduce(_ op _)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fancy Scala way of doing it

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.tester._
import chiseltest.ChiselScalatestTester
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}

class ChiselFuncParam(mathFunc: UInt => UInt => UInt) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val b = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })

  io.out := mathFunc(io.a)(io.b)
}

class CFPTest extends FreeSpec with ChiselScalatestTester with Matchers {
  def add(a: UInt)(b: UInt): UInt = a + b
  def sub(a: UInt)(b: UInt): UInt = a - b

  "add works" in {
    test(new ChiselFuncParam(add)) { c =>
      c.io.a.poke(9.U)
      c.io.b.poke(5.U)
      c.io.out.expect(14.U)
    }
  }
  "sub works" in {
    test(new ChiselFuncParam(sub)) { c =>
      c.io.a.poke(9.U)
      c.io.b.poke(2.U)
      c.io.out.expect(7.U)
    }
  }
}
```

Although it might be clearer to just pass in a string form of the operator and then use simple Scala `if`s to control the appropriate code generation. Something like

```
class MathOp(code: String) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val b = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })

  io.out := (code match {
    case "+" => io.a + io.b
    case "-" => io.a - io.b
    // ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Got it.  I think the part I was missing was to create a stub function with explicit types, rather than passing the operating in directly.

Answer (score 1):

Chick has already provided a good answer, but I want to provide another example to illustrate and explain some of the really powerful features of Chisel and Scala for hardware design. I know you (Guy) probably know most of this but I wanted to provide a detailed answer for anyone else coming across this question.

I'll start with the complete example and then highlight some of the features being used.

```scala
class MyModule[T <: Data](n: Int, gen: T)(op: (T, T) => T) extends Module {
  require(n > 0, "reduce only works on non-empty Vecs")
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in  = Input(Vec(n, gen))
    val out = Output(gen)
  })
  io.out := io.in.reduce(op)
}
```

`[T <: Data]` This is called a [Type Parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html) (`T`) with an [Upper Type Bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) (`<: Data`). This allows us to make the `Module` *generic* to the hardware type with which we parameterize it. We give `T` an upper bound of `Data` (which is a [type from Chisel](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.2.2/chisel3/Data.html)) to tell Scala that this is a hardware type we can use to generate hardware with Chisel. The upper-bound means it must be a *subtype* of Data, which includes all of the Chisel hardware types (eg. `UInt`, `SInt`, `Vec`, `Bundle` and user classes that extend `Bundle`). This is the exact same way that the Chisel constructors like [`Reg(...)` are parameterized](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.2.2/chisel3/Reg$.html).

You will notice that there are [multiple parameter lists](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html), `(n: Int, gen: T)` and `(op: (T, T) => T)`. The first argument, `n: Int`, is a simple integer parameter. The second argument, `gen: T`, is our generic type `T`, and thus a subtype of `Data` that serves as a template for the hardware we will generate inside the Module.

The second parameter list `(op: (T, T) => T)` is a *function*. As a functional programming language, [functions are values in Scala](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-functions-as-variables-values-in-scala-fp), and thus can be used as arguments just like our `Int` argument. `(T, T) => T` reads as a function of two arguments, both of type `T`, that returns a `T`. Remember that `T` is our hardware type that is a subclass of `Data`. Because `op` is in a second parameter list, this is telling Scala that it should infer `T` from `gen`, and then use the same `T` for `op`. For example, if `gen` is `UInt(8.W)`, Scala infers `T` as `UInt`. This then constrains `op` to be a function of type `(UInt, UInt) => UInt`. Bitwise AND is such a function, so we can pass an [anonymous function](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-functional-literals-anonymous-functions-in-scala) to AND two `UInt`s: `(_ & _)`.

Now that we have our abstract, type parameterized `MyModule` class, how do we actually use it? Above I gave snippets of how to use it with `UInt`s, but let's see how to get some actual Verilog:

```scala
object MyMain extends App {
  println(chisel3.Driver.emitVerilog(new MyModule(4, UInt(8.W))(_ & _)))
}
```

Alternatively, we can parameterize `MyModule` with a more complex type:

```scala
class MyBundle extends Bundle {
  val bar = Bool()
  val baz = Bool()
}

object MyMain extends App {
  def combineMyBundle(a: MyBundle, b: MyBundle): MyBundle = {
    val w = Wire(new MyBundle)
    w.bar := a.bar && b.bar
    w.baz := a.baz && b.baz
    w
  }
  println(chisel3.Driver.emitVerilog(new MyModule(4, new MyBundle)(combineMyBundle)))
}
```

We also had to define a function of type `(MyBundle, MyBundle) => MyBundle` which we did with `combineMyBundle`.

You can see a complete, runnable version of the code I presented above on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/X66mgM0nRoikRWhYiscJmw).

I hope someone finds this example useful!